# Mall Map Integration into iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6, dictionary

Hello everyone i am stuck into one problem. I am working on Application in which Mall Map required to integrate.

I need to display Mall map like this:
[image]

I have done proper r&d but not found any solution yet.

Can it be possible if yes then how can i implement this ?

Any hint or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You need GPS on it? Otherwise just display it like a pdf... Or image.

Comment: @waf no i don't want to use GPS.

Comment: Then just display it in a UIImageView.. If you want it to be scrollable put the UIImageView in a UIScrollView

Comment: @lukaswelte yes i can go for this alternate

Comment: please can you describe more about your stuff.? where come from this..? this is PDF or image..?

Comment: @NitinGohel its an image that client shown to me but he needs such kind of map in Application but he don't want to use World Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could display the map in a `UIImage` and place this image in a `UIScrollView`. After that you need to divide the image into region rectangles, each identifying one room.

When the user taps the `UIScrollView` you need to determine which region he tapped on.

Using your room grid you can detect which room he tapped on. Of course this is easier for not zoomed images.

In a zoomed state you need to convert the touched point to the "unzoomed touched point" and check this point for the grid.